# How to detect motion from camera in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, artificial-intelligence, motion-detection

I want to use my mobile camera as a security camera and I want to detect the motion of any object from the camera and trigger the alarm. Is there any way to detect the motion from the camera in flutter for both android and ios?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project like that. Here is how I did it.

You take an image after a certain interval, store it, and then on the next interval you take another one and compare it with the previous one.

The library for comparing images is **image_compare** you can find it on pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be using [Google ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection)

They provide [support for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_object_detection) based on channels.
You can follow [the example](https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/tree/master/packages/example) and use the camera view to get the image input:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  CameraView(
      {Key? key,
      required this.customPaint,
      required this.onImage,
      this.onCameraFeedReady,
      this.onDetectorViewModeChanged,
      this.onCameraLensDirectionChanged,
      this.initialCameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back})
      : super(key: key);

  final CustomPaint? customPaint;
  final Function(InputImage inputImage) onImage;
  final VoidCallback? onCameraFeedReady;
  final VoidCallback? onDetectorViewModeChanged;
  final Function(CameraLensDirection direction)? onCameraLensDirectionChanged;
  final CameraLensDirection initialCameraLensDirection;

  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() => _CameraViewState();
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> {
  static List<CameraDescription> _cameras = [];
  CameraController? _controller;
  int _cameraIndex = -1;
  double _currentZoomLevel = 1.0;
  double _minAvailableZoom = 1.0;
  double _maxAvailableZoom = 1.0;
  double _minAvailableExposureOffset = 0.0;
  double _maxAvailableExposureOffset = 0.0;
  double _currentExposureOffset = 0.0;
  bool _changingCameraLens = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initialize();
  }

  void _initialize() async {
    if (_cameras.isEmpty) {
      _cameras = await availableCameras();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < _cameras.length; i++) {
      if (_cameras[i].lensDirection == widget.initialCameraLensDirection) {
        _cameraIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (_cameraIndex != -1) {
      _startLiveFeed();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stopLiveFeed();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _liveFeedBody());
  }

  Widget _liveFeedBody() {
    if (_cameras.isEmpty) return Container();
    if (_controller == null) return Container();
    if (_controller?.value.isInitialized == false) return Container();
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: _changingCameraLens
                ? Center(
                    child: const Text('Changing camera lens'),
                  )
                : CameraPreview(
                    _controller!,
                    child: widget.customPaint,
                  ),
          ),
          _backButton(),
          _switchLiveCameraToggle(),
          _detectionViewModeToggle(),
          _zoomControl(),
          _exposureControl(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _backButton() => Positioned(
        top: 40,
        left: 8,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: Object(),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
              size: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _detectionViewModeToggle() => Positioned(
        bottom: 8,
        left: 8,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: Object(),
            onPressed: widget.onDetectorViewModeChanged,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.photo_library_outlined,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _switchLiveCameraToggle() => Positioned(
        bottom: 8,
        right: 8,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: Object(),
            onPressed: _switchLiveCamera,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            child: Icon(
              Platform.isIOS
                  ? Icons.flip_camera_ios_outlined
                  : Icons.flip_camera_android_outlined,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _zoomControl() => Positioned(
        bottom: 16,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 250,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Slider(
                    value: _currentZoomLevel,
                    min: _minAvailableZoom,
                    max: _maxAvailableZoom,
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    inactiveColor: Colors.white30,
                    onChanged: (value) async {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentZoomLevel = value;
                      });
                      await _controller?.setZoomLevel(value);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '${_currentZoomLevel.toStringAsFixed(1)}x',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _exposureControl() => Positioned(
        top: 40,
        right: 8,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 250,
          ),
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              width: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black54,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${_currentExposureOffset.toStringAsFixed(1)}x',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 3,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Slider(
                    value: _currentExposureOffset,
                    min: _minAvailableExposureOffset,
                    max: _maxAvailableExposureOffset,
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    inactiveColor: Colors.white30,
                    onChanged: (value) async {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentExposureOffset = value;
                      });
                      await _controller?.setExposureOffset(value);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      );

  Future _startLiveFeed() async {
    final camera = _cameras[_cameraIndex];
    _controller = CameraController(
      camera,
      // Set to ResolutionPreset.high. Do NOT set it to ResolutionPreset.max because for some phones does NOT work.
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
      imageFormatGroup: Platform.isAndroid
          ? ImageFormatGroup.nv21
          : ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888,
    );
    _controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      _controller?.getMinZoomLevel().then((value) {
        _currentZoomLevel = value;
        _minAvailableZoom = value;
      });
      _controller?.getMaxZoomLevel().then((value) {
        _maxAvailableZoom = value;
      });
      _currentExposureOffset = 0.0;
      _controller?.getMinExposureOffset().then((value) {
        _minAvailableExposureOffset = value;
      });
      _controller?.getMaxExposureOffset().then((value) {
        _maxAvailableExposureOffset = value;
      });
      _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage).then((value) {
        if (widget.onCameraFeedReady != null) {
          widget.onCameraFeedReady!();
        }
        if (widget.onCameraLensDirectionChanged != null) {
          widget.onCameraLensDirectionChanged!(camera.lensDirection);
        }
      });
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Future _stopLiveFeed() async {
    await _controller?.stopImageStream();
    await _controller?.dispose();
    _controller = null;
  }

  Future _switchLiveCamera() async {
    setState(() => _changingCameraLens = true);
    _cameraIndex = (_cameraIndex + 1) % _cameras.length;

    await _stopLiveFeed();
    await _startLiveFeed();
    setState(() => _changingCameraLens = false);
  }

  void _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) {
    final inputImage = _inputImageFromCameraImage(image);
    if (inputImage == null) return;
    widget.onImage(inputImage);
  }

  final _orientations = {
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp: 0,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft: 90,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown: 180,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: 270,
  };

  InputImage? _inputImageFromCameraImage(CameraImage image) {
    if (_controller == null) return null;

    // get image rotation
    // it is used in android to convert the InputImage from Dart to Java: https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mlkit_commons/android/src/main/java/com/google_mlkit_commons/InputImageConverter.java
    // `rotation` is not used in iOS to convert the InputImage from Dart to Obj-C: https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mlkit_commons/ios/Classes/MLKVisionImage%2BFlutterPlugin.m
    // in both platforms `rotation` and `camera.lensDirection` can be used to compensate `x` and `y` coordinates on a canvas: https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/example/lib/vision_detector_views/painters/coordinates_translator.dart
    final camera = _cameras[_cameraIndex];
    final sensorOrientation = camera.sensorOrientation;
    // print(
    //     'lensDirection: ${camera.lensDirection}, sensorOrientation: $sensorOrientation, ${_controller?.value.deviceOrientation} ${_controller?.value.lockedCaptureOrientation} ${_controller?.value.isCaptureOrientationLocked}');
    InputImageRotation? rotation;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      rotation = InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(sensorOrientation);
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var rotationCompensation =
          _orientations[_controller!.value.deviceOrientation];
      if (rotationCompensation == null) return null;
      if (camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front) {
        // front-facing
        rotationCompensation = (sensorOrientation + rotationCompensation) % 360;
      } else {
        // back-facing
        rotationCompensation =
            (sensorOrientation - rotationCompensation + 360) % 360;
      }
      rotation = InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(rotationCompensation);
      // print('rotationCompensation: $rotationCompensation');
    }
    if (rotation == null) return null;
    // print('final rotation: $rotation');

    // get image format
    final format = InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw);
    // validate format depending on platform
    // only supported formats:
    // * nv21 for Android
    // * bgra8888 for iOS
    if (format == null ||
        (Platform.isAndroid && format != InputImageFormat.nv21) ||
        (Platform.isIOS && format != InputImageFormat.bgra8888)) return null;

    // since format is constraint to nv21 or bgra8888, both only have one plane
    if (image.planes.length != 1) return null;
    final plane = image.planes.first;

    // compose InputImage using bytes
    return InputImage.fromBytes(
      bytes: plane.bytes,
      metadata: InputImageMetadata(
        size: Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
        rotation: rotation, // used only in Android
        format: format, // used only in iOS
        bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow, // used only in iOS
      ),
    );
  }
}
```